# JQuery Full Height 75% width Sliding Page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a sliding page that covers about 75% of the width of my site and once clicked away recedes to about 15% of the site (on the left). The slider is going to have content on it, but I do not want the sliding page to affect the content that is on the page behind it. I haven't had any luck finding coding help with these specific issue. Any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery animate function to animate the sliding:

```
$("#slideLeft").click(function () {
    $("#slider").animate({left:-550}, 2000);
});​
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/FPVmc/27/